# Defining constants and operators in Irony

Tags: c#, boolean-expression, expression-evaluation, irony

I'm new to [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) and the whole language implementation shebang, so I've been playing around with the [ExpressionEvaluator](http://irony.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/acd25bbbf17e#Irony.Samples/ExpressionEvaluator/ExpressionEvaluatorGrammar.cs) sample that comes with the [Irony source](http://irony.codeplex.com/releases/view/8499), which seems to (almost) suit my needs for a project I'm working on.

However, I would like it to support booleans as well, so I've added comparison operators to the list of binary operators, as such:

```
BinOp.Rule = ToTerm("+") | "-" | "*" | "/" | "**"
  | "==" | "<=" | ">=" | "<" | ">" | "!=" | "<>"; // added comparison operators
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
x = 1
y = 2
eval = x < 2
eval2 = y < x
bool = true
bool2 = (eval == eval2)
```

Because of the added binary operators, it succeeds in parsing the above. However, when compiling and running the code, it fails on the last two lines.

1. The `bool = true` line fails with the message: *Error: Variable true not defined. At (5:8).* How do I define *true* and *false* as constants?
2. The `bool2 = (eval == eval2)` line fails with the message: *Error: Operator '==' is not defined for types System.Boolean and System.Boolean. At (6:15).*

**Edit: Solved both issues, see answer below.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, solved both issues. Hopefully this can be of help to others.

### Issue 1

As far as I can understand from [this Irony discussion thread](http://irony.codeplex.com/discussions/21546), **true** and **false** constants should be treated as predefined global variables, rather than be implemented directly as part of the language. As such, I define these as globals when creating the **ScriptInterpreter**.

One should be aware that by doing it this way, they can be modified by the script as they are not constants, but simply global variables. There might be a better way to do this, but this will do for now:

```
var interpreter = new Irony.Interpreter.ScriptInterpreter(
  new ExpressionEvaluatorGrammar());
interpreter.Globals["true"] = true;
interpreter.Globals["false"] = false;
interpreter.Evaluate(parsedSample);
```

### Issue 2

First off, the `<>` operator should come before the `<` and `>` operators in the binary operator rule:

```
BinOp.Rule = ToTerm("+") | "-" | "*" | "/" | "**"
  | "<>" | "==" | "<=" | ">=" | "<" | ">" | "!="; // added comparison operators
```

Next, I created a custom implementation of the **LanguageRuntime** class which implements the necessary operators.

```
public class CustomLanguageRuntime : LanguageRuntime
{
  public CustomLanguageRuntime(LanguageData data)
    : base(data)
  {
  }

  public override void InitOperatorImplementations()
  {
    base.InitOperatorImplementations();
    AddImplementation("<>", typeof(bool), (x, y) => (bool)x != (bool)y);
    AddImplementation("!=", typeof(bool), (x, y) => (bool)x != (bool)y);
    AddImplementation("==", typeof(bool), (x, y) => (bool)x == (bool)y);
  }
}
```

In the **ExpressionEvaluatorGrammar**, override the **CreateRuntime** method to return an instance of **CustomLanguageRuntime**:

```
public override LanguageRuntime CreateRuntime(LanguageData data)
{
  return new CustomLanguageRuntime(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a lot of time. If anyone else comes across this, AddImplementation() no longer exists. Instead I used AddBinary(), e.g.: AddBinary(ExpressionType.NotEqual, typeof(DateTime), (x, y) => (DateTime)x != (DateTime)y);